# xmpp/jabber for chat for dating site?

Tags: chat, xmpp, ejabberd

we're in the process of adding text chat to our dating site and I'm considering using xmpp - specifically ejabberd on the server side, and we will be implementing an ajax client.

i'd like to hear from someone with good xmpp experience - is it architecturally suitable for chat on a dating site ? in chat on a dating site anybody can chat one-on-one with anybody - they don't have to be on your 'friends' list. Also we do not want a chat room - only one-on-one chat.

Or is xmpp more suitable for the model where someone has to add you to their friends list before you can with them ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP should work fine for you.  Ejabberd, depending on the number of concurrent users you have, should be a fine starting point.  Consider using a BOSH library like [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) in your HTML client.  If you use that library, you'll want a copy of [Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery](http://professionalxmpp.com/), which has examples of all of the code you'll need.

You do NOT need to have presence subscriptions in place to send chat messages between users, except in specific server implementations like GoogleTalk.  Reducing the number of presence subscriptions will also drastically increase the number of users you can handle concurrently.